# バッチファイルが途中で止まってしまいます

Tags: windows, batch-file

win10を使っています。
コマンドプロンプトを利用して色々やろうとしているのですが、１個目のコマンドが実行されたところで止まってしまい、２個目以降が動きません。
pythonから起動するパターンと、バッチファイルから起動するパターンの両方を試しているのですが、両方同じようになってしまいます。
いま非常にシンプルな例として以下のようなバッチファイルを作って実行したところ、画像のような結果になりました。

```
cmd /k dir
cmd /k tree
```

[image: １つ実行すると止まる]

１個目だけ実行されて止まっています。

毎回ここでつまずいており困っています。どうしたらよいか教えていただけると助かります。

なお
`cmd /k dir`
という書き方の意図は以下です。

- はじめ　`dir`とだけ書いた
- するとすぐにウィンドウが閉じてしまった
- 調べるとオプションとして　`/k`　を使うとウィンドウが閉じないようだ

このあたりも含めて考え方に間違いがあればご指摘ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

バッチファイルの中身は単に以下のような記述ではだめでしょうか。

dirtree.bat

```
dir
tree
```

バッチファイルは実行させたいコマンドを列挙しておけば順に実行してくれますので、今回の例であればわざわざ`cmd`の引数に渡す必要は無いと思います。

**追記**
作成したバッチファイルをダブルクリックで実行した場合は、処理が終了するとウインドウも閉じてしまいます。もしウインドウを開いたまま(結果を確認したい)場合には、バッチファイルの最後に`pause`コマンドの行を追記してください。一連の処理が完了後、「続行するには何かキーを押してください...」と表示され、入力待ちの状態になります。

```
dir
tree
pause
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。そのように書くとウィンドウがすぐにとじてしまわないでしょうか？

Comment: 試した限りはウインドウは開いたままでしたが、念を押すなバッチファイルの最後に`pause`コマンドを追記してみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。pauseを書いたら閉じなくなりました。しかしpauseなしだと閉じてしまいます。私の環境だけなのでしょうか。。　プロンプトの理解を深めたいので、もし思い当たる点あれば教えてくださると嬉しいです。

Comment: 私が試したのは予めコマンドプロンプトを起動した状態で実行したからでした。バッチファイルをダブルクリックで実行した場合は処理が終わるとウインドウは閉じてしまいますね。回答に説明を追記したので確認してください。